# Runtime error '2105' "You can't go to the specified record"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button on a form whose purpose is to add a new record to the underlying
table.

The OnClick Event code for the button looks like

```
  me.dirty = false

  if me.NewRecord then
     msgBox("new record")
  else
     msgBox("not new record")
  end if

  doCmd.goToRecord record := acNewRecord
```

The message box is needed to make sure that I am not already operating on a new record.

When I click the button, I get a Runtime error 2105 "You can't go to the specified record"

Does someone know why this is?

Rene

Comment: what is the query/datasource behind the form? Is it as simple as a table to be able to add new record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never Mind, I found the problem

I should have used

```
doCmd.goToRecord record := acNewRec
```

instead of

```
doCmd.goToRecord record := acNewRecord
```

Yet, why access won't tell me that it doesn't know about acNewRecord....

**Edit**: Of course David was right: I haven't set `OPTION EXPLICIT`.

Comment: Sounds like your code module doesn't have OPTION EXPLICIT set in the declarations section. If it does and you compile, acNewRecord will be identified as an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the 2105 issue by selecting a unique record identifier for the underlying linked table that was the record source for the MS Access form.

Answer (score 0):

i also have faced this issue and in my case this belowed solution worked well
try this ,

if form doesn't allow you to add new record then make sure that
before the form opensup all the other forms that also used tha same table as datasource are needs to be close first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue that was related to the form's property sheet, it had Data Entry, Allow additions / dleetions / edits / filters set to NO. Turning that back to yes fixed it, allowed me to create new records.

Answer (score -1):

double click on the up left point on the small black squere in the form to have the main properties of the form, then go to the data tap and click the Record source button, you will see that the form is linked to another table which is prevent the form to add new records, remove that table, and I hope that will solve your problem. 
Salam...

Comment: Er, the problem was identified as a typo in code. How does this add anything to an already resolved question?